# Query PFUser currentUser for a custom field

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using the parse framework and would like to know how I can query a column that is located in the PFUser table.

Here is some example code:

```
//Adds athlete_id column to roster table    
PFObject *roster = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Roster"];
roster[@"athlete_id"] = answer;
[roster save];

//Adds the rosters objectId to an array (athlete_id) in the User table. 
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
[currentUser addObject:roster.objectId forKey:@"athlete_id"];
[currentUser saveInBackground];
```

With the above code end up getting an array of objectsID's within the User class in a column named "athlete_id".

Im having a problem actually retrieving this array from the User class. Here is how I am attempting to get the array from the user:

```
FQuery *query = [PFUser query];;
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"athelete_id"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            NSLog(@"athlete %@", objects);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        }
    }];
```

I want to grab the array that is contained in athlete_id column for the current user, but the objects array is empty on this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a query.

Just do this:

```
NSString *athleteId = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"athelete_id"];

NSLog(@"The athlete id is %@", athleteId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This seems like a much easier way but the value of athleteId is now null. The content in the column "athlete_id" is an array of objectsId's from the roster table.

Comment: @klmitchell2 You want every user's object id or just the current user's? Is there any data inside the athlete_Id column?

Comment: Please note that for any new fields added to USER class, you need to logout and log back in for them to be visible in your app.

Comment: @GrandSteph This was my issue as well.